# Selenium test difference between an hidden element and an element not in the viewport

Tags: c#, html, selenium, google-chrome

A selenium element that's disabled with the ng-show attribute=false has values Displayed=false and Enabled=true.
A selenium element that's enabled with the ng-show attribute=true but falls out of the viewport has the values Displayed=false and Enabled=true.
The Displayed flag is manipulated by the html page ng-show value and on the other hand autonomous by Chrome.
How can I detect the difference between these situations?
The reason why I need to know this is that the method

```
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(element).Perform();
```

throws an exception when the element doesn't exist.
This happerns after update of Chrome (77) and ChromeDriver (76)
So before executing this method, I need to know if the element exists, both 
inside or outside the viewport.

Comment: You'll need to compare the X,Y coordinates of the element to the X,Y coordinates of the viewport. If you cannot do that, then you can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Greg. That's the first thing.
The second is that I will know if the value or condition of the ng-show attribute is set.